# What can cause a sporadic "-2147352567 The data has been changed" error?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

One of our forms keeps generating this error message sporadically.  The issue occurs on our Order form, which is bound to a linked SQL Server 2008 table.  Having printed an advice note (using a report), the order status is then set to 'Printed Order'.  At this point, I'm sporadically seeing a "-2147352567 The data has been changed" error.  I would say 95% of the time, this doesn't occur, but it's that other 5% that's causing us headaches (and numerous support calls).

Oddly, closing the form and trying the same action on the order causes the same error message, but closing the database and trying again works fine.

It's as if there are some uncommitted changes to the table/record the form is bound to, which exist even when there are no forms, reports, etc open.

The code looks like this:

```
Select Case Me.txtCurrentStatus
  Case NEW_ORDER, UNPRINTED_ORDER:
    Me.txtCurrentStatus = PRINTED_ORDER
End Select
'Commit changes
If Me.Dirty = True Then Me.Dirty = False
```

Comment: save also BEFORE printing, at least to see if there's an impact ? What is the back-end ? Jet/ACE or SQL Server ? Does your table have a PK ?

Comment: Hi iDevelop.  The back end is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP3 and we're using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 to connect.  Yes, the table has a primary key.  The issue only occurs once every 20 orders... I can't discern any particular pattern or reason for the issue occurring.  Seems completely random.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table your interacting with?

Comment: Does your table include a timestamp field ? If not, add it (and relink table)

Comment: Brad - Yes, there's a delete trigger on the table... but I'm not deleting anything.

Comment: iDevelop - No, there isn't a timestamp field.  Can you explain, or point me to an explanation of why that would cure the issue?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you _delete_ anything. If any of the data _change_ in anyway for any of the records you are showing you'll get this error. So if you have a date modified column and someone changes data then once you update the modification date the data in your record set in access is no longer in sync with the data in the table and the SQL server library doesn't like this.

Comment: iDevelop, I've created a new column - RowVersion as timestamp - and so far, I haven't had any reports of this issue reoccurring.  It'll be a couple of days before I know for sure.  Unfortunately, I can't mark your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@iDevelop actually prompted me to look into adding a timestamp to the table, so I take only partial credit ;)...

In short - when using linked tables in Microsoft Access, if the table does not contain a column of type **timestamp**, Access will compare every column in the table to see if the data has been changed since the record was retrieved.  There are several data types that Access is unable to check reliably (see article below).  Simply adding a column of type **timestamp** changes this behaviour and instead, Access only checks to see if the **rowversion** has changed... which makes this check more reliable and also improves performance.

Oddly, this isn't really a timestamp at all - it's a rowversion, but in SQL Server 2008, which I am using **rowversion** isn't available via the GUI.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204%28v=sql.90%29.aspx.

> Probably the leading cause of updatability problems in Office Access–linked tables is that Office Access is unable to verify whether data on the server matches what was last retrieved by the dynaset being updated. If Office Access cannot perform this verification, it assumes that the server row has been modified or deleted by another user and it aborts the update.
>
> There are several types of data that Office Access is unable to check reliably for matching values. These include large object types, such as **text**, **ntext**, **image**, and the **varchar(max)**, **nvarchar(max)**, and **varbinary(max)** types introduced in SQL Server 2005. In addition, floating-point numeric types, such as **real** and **float**, are subject to rounding issues that can make comparisons imprecise, resulting in cancelled updates when the values haven't really changed. Office Access also has trouble updating tables containing bit columns that do not have a default value and that contain null values.
>
> A quick and easy way to remedy these problems is to add a **timestamp** column to the table on SQL Server. The data in a **timestamp** column is completely unrelated to the date or time. Instead, it is a binary value that is guaranteed to be unique across the database and to increase automatically every time a new value is assigned to any column in the table. The ANSI standard term for this type of column is rowversion. This term is supported in SQL Server.
>
> Office Access automatically detects when a table contains this type of column and uses it in the WHERE clause of all **UPDATE** and **DELETE** statements affecting that table. This is more efficient than verifying that all the other columns still have the same values they had when the dynaset was last refreshed.

Comment: In your original question, you left out the HUGE fact that you are using a server database. When using a file share back end (JET/ACE) then the rowversion logic does not apply.

Comment: Hi Albert.  Quite right... I'll add that into the question so that it makes more sense for anyone else that's banging their head against a brick wall trying to figure this one out.  2 full days without the problem now!  :)